# Does a maven repository have a standard format?

Tags: maven, repository, nexus

How are repos laid out?  Are they the same?  If so, who specifies the format.

Comment: [Check this](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Repository+Layout+-+Final)

Comment: No formal specification for Maven repository manager's file layout (Metadata files, index file format etc). Question should be directed to Sonatype the makers of Maven, I suppose they'd just tell you to use Nexus :-)

Answer (score 10):

Repository layout for Maven is defined very strictly. Maven itself is the tool that completely handles the repository.

```
/$groupIdWithSlashes/$artifactId/$version/$artifactId-$version.$extension
/$groupIdWithSlashes/$artifactId/$version/$artifactId-$version-$classifier.$extension
```

Read more [here on details of the layout](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+Layout+-+Final), and [here on details of metadata files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+Metadata).

Note that [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) has similar layout in its storage, but (in some cases) slightly different format of metadata.xml file.

Other repository managers can have completely different layout in its internal storage - like [Artifactory](https://sourceforge.net/projects/artifactory/). Anyway, the URL structure must be (and is) identical.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  That page doesn't seem to address the meta data files that I see in my local repo; are they part of the "standard" repo format as well.  And, if I look inside of my nexus repo, will be identical to the local repo?

Comment: what is your exact question, are you just curious or trying to solve a problem?

Comment: thanks to @xenoterracide and Ross Black, the links are fixed now

Comment: they're broken again.