# Maven repo module and parent at the same level

Tags: maven

I have created a simple maven project with a parent pom and a module pom. When i execute a mvn clean install i notice that the parent and the module are in the same level.

Structure of the project in the local repo:

```
-parent folder
-module folder
```

While I expected something like that:

```
-parent folder
   +—-module folder
```

Is this normal ?

What happened if two modules have the same name in this case ?

Comment: Can you explain more detail what your problem is? Can you format the post better ...otherwise it's hard to read...

Comment: I added more details, i would like to know if its normal that parent folder and module folder in my local repo are on the same level. I expected to have module folder in the parent folder

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about the local repo usually located at `~/.m2/repository`, yes, that is normal. You have to distinguish between the folder layout within the repository and the folder layout for your development.

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370666/does-a-maven-repository-have-a-standard-format), the artifacts are always in a folder structure according to their coordinates (`groupId`, `artifactId` and `version`).

```
groupIdSplitAtDots/artifactId/version
```

Whether some artifacts are modules of another is completely irrelevant for the directory-layout of the **local repository**.

If you have e.g. the artifacts `com.organisation.topic:artifact-parent:1.2`, `com.organisation.topic:artifact-module1:1.2` and `com.organisation.topic:artifact-module2:1.2`, the folder structure will be:

```
com
|-- organisation
    |-- topic
        |-- artifact-parent
            |-- 1.2
        |-- artifact-module1
            |-- 1.2
        |-- artifact-module2
            |-- 1.2
```

Note, that for **development** it is usually a good idea to have the parent module in a parent folder, resulting in a layout like this:

```
artifact-parent
|-- artifact-module1
|-- artifact-module2
```

As per your second question, identical module names (`artifactId`s) are not allowed. Regarding the `artifactId` [the docs](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.4/maven-model/maven.html#class_project) state:

> The identifier for this artifact that is unique within the group given by the group ID.

Comment: Ok so its normal to have parent and module in the same level in my repo but imagine the case i have two modules with the same how its manages in my repo ?

Comment: @mrt66 Sorry, I overread your second question. I updated my answer accordingly